# single click emits event multiple times through reducer in react-redux

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a click event addtocartAction

```
document.getElementsByClassName("addtocartbox")[0].addEventListener('click',function() {
     that.props.addtocartAction(item.id,1);      
});
```

which is dispatched as

```
const mapDispatchToProps={
    addtocartAction:(id,count)=>{
        return {
            type:'ADD_TO_CART',
            payload:{id:id,count:count}
        }
    }    
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

The purpose of the action is to
i) add an object as {id:'33', count: 1} to an array if any object with this id does not already exist in the array
ii) the any object with the id already exists in the array, then count is to added to the existing count of the object.

The reducer is as follows:

```
export default function(state=[],action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':
            if(!action.payload.id===undefined)return state;
            let index=state.findIndex(item=>item.id==action.payload.id);
            console.log(action.payload, index);
            if(index>=0){
                let counter=state[index]["count"];
                state[index]["count"]=counter+action.payload.count;
            }else{
                state.push(action.payload);
            }
            console.log(state, index);
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

The problem is when a click event is occurred, the event emits multiple times thus adding multiple object to the array.Before any click, the array looks empty in the console which changes multiple times after single click. The console images are as follows

[image]
The below image is after one click:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem in the past, and was because every time an action was dispatched and the change of states affects my component, this reloaded the definitions inside, including the windows events. And this only get worst.
So, every time you click, new listeners will be created and new actions will be dispatched

I recommend to use this in the rendering code

```
onClick={ handleClick.bind(this, item.id) }
```

Comment: Surprisingly, I found the answer helpful, as I structured the event code that way and it resulted in the correct way, though, I am not still clear why, at first it went wrong and why, on the contrary, restructuring the event method made it right.